# PyQt can't set a value for an object from a dialog in main window

Tags: python, oop, text, pyqt

I have a Main program that calls various Dialogs with their own GUIs. Basically what I want to do is to set up a value in Main for an object that is another class:

```
class ZoneManager(QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_zzzMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        mainWindow.Ui_zzzMainWindow.__init__(self)
.....
    def cookie_find(self):
            match = re.search('cookie_id=(.*?)\"', page).group(1)
            rga = str(match)
            print (match)
            dialog = QDialog()
            dialog.ui = rga_session.Ui_rga_sessionDialog()
            dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
            dialog.exec_()
```

> ```
>      dialog.ui.rgaSessionText.setText(rga) # <<<<I want to set the text into a QLineEdit object
> ```
>
> but I can't.
>   The dialog is in a separate file and made it in QTDesigner with standard 2 methods:
>   from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

```
class Ui_rga_sessionDialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, rga_sessionDialog):
        rga_sessionDialog.setObjectName("rga_sessionDialog")
        self.rgaSessionText = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(rga_sessionDialog)
        self.rgaSessionText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 261, 21))
        self.rgaSessionText.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.rgaSessionText.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.rgaSessionText.setObjectName("rgaSessionText")
..........
    def retranslateUi(self, rga_sessionDialog):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
.....
```

Who I can I append that text that I found from Regex into "rgaSessionText" ? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to communicate between the mainwindow and other dialogs through the signal-slot way.

In your ZoneManager class, define:

```
settextsignal= pyqtSignal(str)
```

In your Ui_rga_sessionDialog class, define:

```
@pyqtSlot(str)
def textUpdate(self, rga):
    self.rgaSessionText.setText(rga)
```

Then in your cookie_find method, after initializing the Ui_rga_sessionDialog, put:

```
self.settextsignal.connect(dialog.ui.textUpdate)
```

Then whenever you want to set the text, just call:

```
self.settextsignal.emit(text)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!